# Как работать с кнопками?

Tags: android

Мне нужно отображать в actionBar либо кнопку "reload" либо кнопку "home" в зависимости от текущей активити. Проиллюстрирую:
[image]

Как добавлять отдельно кнопку home - научился (использую actionBarSherlock)
Осталось разобраться с тем, как отображать/скрывать кнопку reload. Не получается сделать это в onCreateOptionsMenu просто достав нужную кнопку по id - вылетает ошибка.
У меня есть /menu/menu.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
     android:id="@+id/reload_button"
     android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate">
</item>
```

И еще интересует вопрос как сделать так, чтобы текст был по середине actionBar.

Answer (score 1):

1) Отображать/скрывать кнопку reload:

```
MenuItem menuItem;

...

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.reload_button);
    return true;
}
```

И дальше использовать:

```
menuItem.setVisible(false);
```

2) Чтобы текст был посередине, нужно делать свой layout как кастомную вьюшку у `actionBar`

```
actionBar.setCustomView();
```

Comment: 1) А где нужно вызывать menuItem.setVisible(false)?    
2) Кастомная вьшка у actionBar - это что?

Comment: 1) в том участке кода, где требуется показ/скрытие данного элемента меню
2) это означает, что вы делаете некий `LinerLayout` в котором предположительно будет `TextView` и вставляете в 
> actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.*custom_layout*);

Comment: А можно ли в этой кастомной вьюхе задвать показ/скрытие каких-то элементов?